# What is the meaning of "le poil de la barbe"?

Tags: sens, noms, mots-composés

**The definition of le poil:**

[Académie Française](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9P3080)

[image]

> Au singulier, avec un sens collectif. **Désigne l’ensemble de ces**
> **filaments** sur une partie du corps humain. Le poil de la barbe.

[CNRTL](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/poil) has the same definition.

After seeing the definition of *le poil*, is it correct to say **le poil de la barbe** means **beard hair**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct but not common.

We normally either use the plural to mean "beard hair" (***les poils de la barbe***) or, more frequently, simply say ***la barbe*** but the singular ***le poil de la barbe*** is possible as a collective. This singular is not usable in every context.

Here are anyway  other cases where a collective singular noun can be used to name body parts:

> ***le pied marin, l'oreille fine, l'œil perçant, la dent dure, le cheveu clairsemé**.*

You would also say about an animal *il a **le poil brillant*** which is equivalent to *il a **les poils brillants***.

Comment: Usage courant : singulier + *adjectif*. « Il a le poil de la barbe *poivre et sel* ».

Comment: @Personne Oui, c'est ce que je veux dire par *a collective*. C'est quand même moins courant que « Il a la barbe poivre et sel ».

Comment: Exact, mais en considérant poil par poil, avoir “le poil de la barbe poivre et sel” n'inclus pas toute la barbe … alors, la grisaille entame le slogan « Ce n'est qu'un début continuons d‘grisouillet !! » et fini par gagner à l'usure, avec de plus en plus de sel, de moins en moins de poivre.